# Why won't my ListItem allow me to add data into extra columns?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listboxitem

For some reason, the below code started breaking when trying to add data into the .List(0, 1) column. I have no idea why I'm not allowed to add more than one column of data into my ListItem anymore as the .AddItem command gives me 10 columns to work with and I've set my columns to 10 already. Is there some line I'm missing that prevents me from adding data past the .List(0, 0) position?

```
Private Sub ListBox3_Click()

Me.InfoBox.Clear
Me.InfoBox.ColumnCount = 10
Me.InfoBox.ColumnWidths = "20;20;20;20;20;20;20;20;20;20"
Me.InfoBox.Font.Size = 10
Me.InfoBox.Font.Bold = False
Me.InfoBox.ListIndex = -1

With Me.InfoBox
    .AddItem
    .List(0, 0) = "A"
    .List(0, 1) = "B"
    .List(0, 2) = "C"
    .List(0, 3) = "D"
    .List(0, 4) = "E"
    .List(0, 5) = "F"
    .List(0, 6) = "G"
    .List(0, 7) = "H"
    .List(0, 8) = "I"
    .List(0, 9) = "J"
End With

End Sub
```

It worked fine for all 10 columns until I changed a loop that goes after this code. I changed everything back, but no dice.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. Commented out the `.List(0, 0) = "A"` and changed the AddItem line to `.AddItem "A"` and got the same error.

Comment: So I must've messed with a property I shouldn't have. I deleted my listbox, put in a new one, then renamed it to InfoBox and it works now. Wonder what it was.

Comment: A better approach would be to make a 2D variant array that holds the values you want in the list, and assign that array to `.InfoBox.List`. Note that the `With Me.InfoBox` block could very well (should?) encompass the half-dozen instructions on above the `.AddItem` call.